# Do firewalls drop udp dns queries that are longer than 512 bytes?

Tags: security, domain-name-system, firewall

bottom line:
DNS' RFC notes that DNS queries over UDP are limited to 512 bytes. Does anybody know if this is enforced by major corporate firewalls?

long story:
My company develops a product that should communicate between data centers. Since the typical user of this product (performance engineer) would not have access to firewall's settings, we would like to develop a method that bypasses firewalls with good rates of success. We thought of tunneling the application data over DNS TXT queries, since it seems that (within the WAN) firewalls tend to let DNS queries pass by. However, we are not very knowledgeable about common firewall behavior and would like some help. Specifically, we are wondering whether the big-brand firewalls block DNS queries over UDP that are longer than 512 bytes.

Thanks,

n

Comment: Thank all for your great advice! If I could accept every one of your answers I would do that, but I had to pick one

Comment: -1 for saying that the RFC limit the size to 512 bytes. Check them first. RFC 2671, which suppressed this limit, is more than ten years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, firewalls don't habitually drop big DNS queries like that, as far as I'm aware.  What you want to look at for your problem is existing implementations of IP over DNS, such as dns2tcp, nstx, or iodine.  They'll show you exactly how it can be done.

Comment: Unfortunately, and despite the DNS standards, dropping DNS packets over 512 bytes is *very* common. See for instance the ICANN report at http://www.icann.org/committees/security/sac035.pdf

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about real, proper, enterprise firewalls you're *probably* OK, although Cisco PIXes tend to come with a default setting that does limit packets to 512 bytes.

If on the other you're talking about low end firewalls, SOHO routers, etc, you're quite likely to come unstuck.

For a full treatise on these issues with low end kit see [RFC 5625](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5625) and ICANN SSAC report [SAC035](http://www.icann.org/en/committees/security/sac035.pdf).  Obligatory disclaimer - I wrote these documents.  DNS packet truncation is something of a speciality of mine...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "not generally".

With EDNS they don't even have the 512 byte UDP limitation.

See the wiki page for some pointers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDNS

What's far more likely is people thinking DNS is UDP only, and ignore that TCP is *required* not optional. We often have to run public DNS servers behind others firewalls and making them understand that we need TCP not just open to us but the world is a pain.

Comment: Oh yes, blocking TCP/53 >fumes<

Comment: For recent work on DNS and TCP see http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-dnsext-dns-tcp-requirements-00

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension to the RFC known as [EDNS0](http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=2671), which implements the ability to extend DNS messages beyond 512 bytes on UDP transports. Historically some firewalls have been known to block the use of this extension. For instance some older PIX and ASA firmwares will drop by default as [exampled here](http://djberriman.blogspot.com/2007/11/cisco-firewall-dns-packet-size-setting.html).

Chances are that *most* firewalls out there today don't exhibit this behaviour. But there's no guarantee that you won't walk into one out in the wild. There is also a chance that any deep packet inspection of your traffic could result it in being blocked as an anomaly.

Furthermore you should bear in mind (if you haven't already) that by using UDP you will have to build transmission control into your application layer, rather than relying on the transport (namely TCP) to provide it. Be sure to follow **womble**'s advice about observing existing DNS tunnelling implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Alnitak's good summary, see also an [excellent tool to test your DNS setup](https://www.dns-oarc.net/oarc/services/replysizetest) and see if it lets packets > 512 bytes go (as it should).

Here is an example of a broken DNS at an important IAP in France:

```
% dig +short rs.dns-oarc.net txt
rst.x486.rs.dns-oarc.net.
rst.x454.x486.rs.dns-oarc.net.
rst.x384.x454.x486.rs.dns-oarc.net.
"213.228.63.58 lacks EDNS, defaults to 512"
"213.228.63.58 DNS reply size limit is at least 486 bytes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Some older firewalls do.

This is a classic problem with Cisco Pix firewalls.
Google for *cisco pix dns edns0* and you'll find a bunch of info on this.

For example http://homepages.tesco.net/J.deBoynePollard/FGA/dns-edns0-and-firewalls.html